# Visualization of time curvature of spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor

The [Flamm's paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Flamm%27s_paraboloid) is a slice of the Schwarzschild metric by two spatial dimensions. This shows the space dilation, but without the time component doesn't really give much insight into the geodesics. Is it possible to somehow plot a slice by the time and one spatial dimension instead?

Comment: It takes a bit of imagination and working through some math to understand, but [Penrose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram) are very useful for visualizing certain symmetric spacetimes.

Answer (score 0):

The metric signature of the timelike surface does not match signature of any surface in 3D space so the correspondence between distances in the picture and spacetime intervals in the Schwarzschild will not be as direct as it is in Flamm's paraboloid.